# Regular expression in date time atrr

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an attribute that contains the joining date for a user and it's returned in this syntax `25-12-2018 10:31:33`, i want to take the date only from it, i tried regular expression but i couldn't figure out how to do it, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

No need of regex just split with `space` and take **0<sup>th</sup>** index element.

```js
let str = `25-12-2018 10:31:33`

console.log(str.split(' ')[0])
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that it's in react native and I'm using {this.state.info.join_date} how can i apply your solution on this statement please?

Comment: @MaryJane `{this.state.info.join_date.split(" ")[0]}` you can use like this

Comment: @MaryJane you need to provide more context than, what is `console.log(this.state.info)` output ?

Comment: it's returning undefined but when i remove the split and reload it returns data correctly, how is that?